# Contradictory condition checks on Where with a Case Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to check two Contradictory conditions on a WHERE clause for a same field using CASE;

If I extract the thing I want, shows below

```
WHERE FULFILMENT_STATUS_CODE != 'CNL'
WHERE FULFILMENT_STATUS_CODE = 'FUL'
```

They way I tried (and want) as follows, But I wonder how to have != in her

```
WHERE
    FULFILMENT_STATUS_CODE =
    CASE @pFILTER_TYPE
        WHEN 1 THEN 'CNL' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'FUL' 
    END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `CASE` in a `WHERE` but `OR` and `AND`:

```
WHERE 
    ( @pFILTER_TYPE = 1 AND FULFILMENT_STATUS_CODE <> 'CNL' )
OR 
    ( @pFILTER_TYPE = 2 AND FULFILMENT_STATUS_CODE = 'FUL' )
```

But instead of evaluating the parameter for every record you could also use an `IF...ELSE` in this stored-procedure with two different queries. That's more verbose but also more efficient.